# ASP.NET checkbox doesn't fire check changed event on first load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two checkboxes

```
<td class="new-wf-step-action-zone">
    <asp:checkbox runat="server" ID="cbMarriedYes" Text="Yes" OnCheckedChanged="cbMarriedYes_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
    <asp:checkbox runat="server" ID="cbMarriedNo" Text="No" OnCheckedChanged="cbMarriedNo_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="true"/>
</td>
```

They will not fire the check changed event the first time they are clicked after page load. Any subsequent clicks work as expected.

`EnableViewState = true`.

Any suggestions are welcome, this is driving me nuts!

Here are the event handlers

```
Protected Async Sub cbSameAddressYes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If cbSameAddressYes.Checked = True Then
            cbSameAddressNo.Checked = False
            GetCustomerAddress(CustomerId)

            tbAddress.Enabled = False
            tbcity.Enabled = False
            tbZip.Enabled = False
            ddlState.Enabled = False
            btnSaveAddress.Enabled = True
        End If

        Await SaveData(False, True).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Await SaveVerificationData(SysLeadVerificationTopicType.CustomerSpouseAddress, SysLeadWorkflowStepVerificationType.Yes)
        'Await LoadData().ConfigureAwait(False)
        OnCompleteStatusUpdated(LeadWorkflowStepType.SpousalConsent, IsCompleted)
        UpdateUI(pnlWfStepContent, InitUiJs, IsCompleted, IsCollapsed)

    End Sub
```

```
   Protected Async Sub cbSameAddressNo_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        tbAddress.Enabled = True
        tbcity.Enabled = True
        tbZip.Enabled = True
        ddlState.Enabled = True

        Await CustomerSpouseDomain.DeactivateCustomerSpouse(CorrelationId, CustomerId).ConfigureAwait(False)

        Await SaveData(False, True).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Await SaveVerificationData(SysLeadVerificationTopicType.CustomerSpouseAddress, SysLeadWorkflowStepVerificationType.No)
        'Await LoadData().ConfigureAwait(False)
        OnCompleteStatusUpdated(LeadWorkflowStepType.SpousalConsent, IsCompleted)
        UpdateUI(pnlWfStepContent, InitUiJs, IsCompleted, IsCollapsed)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Using `async` methods in WebForms Server Control event-handlers is not supported. ASP.NET WebForms's `Page` class only supports `async` methods via `this.RegisterAsyncTask` in `OnLoad` (and in raw `IAsyncHttpHandler` implementations), _and nowhere else_ - which basically means you cannot use it in server-side event-handlers (this is because WebForms predates `async` by 10 years and MS only made minimal changes to WebForms to support it). But anyway you _really_ should be using ASP.NET Core - or at least ASP.NET MVC - why are you using WebForms today? It's been obsolete for 12 years now.

Comment: @Dai Not my choice, that's what our app was developed in 15 years ago.  We're planning to move to Razor but that still a year or so off.

Comment: Why is the routine marked as async? You have a await, so ZERO advantages exist anyway, since the code waits!!! The code HAS to finish before the page can be rendered and sent back to client - so you gain zero in performance. Does not explain why first click does not work - but then again, all code behind has to finish anyway, and THEN the page is sent back down to client side. And any update to the UI from code behind? You not see it until such time all code exits, and the whole page is sent down to the client side - so some sort of "notion" to wait, then update page makes zero sense here.

Comment: I would remove the async from this page - you can't speed up async code as it is written anyway (regardless of if it could work or not). With the awaits, you halt the code, but in a post back, you can only ONE time update the UI parts - but they don't appear until such time the page is sent back to client - so you can't get better UI update performance this way anyway. It is possible that the async code is the reason for the failure - remember, if the code falls through, then the web page WILL get sent back to client - any additional running code at that point CAN NOT update the UI - too late.